# Include string before repeated word

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I'm trying to get the words just before **OR**. So given the string:

`twitter OR facebook AND NOT (hello OR p )`

I'd like to get: `twitter` and `hello`.

Below is my code. What I have tried so far is getting the `twitter` string but I'm getting *"OR facebook AND NOT (hello "* instead of just `hello`:

```js
var string2 = "twitter OR facebook AND NOT (hello OR p )"

var result = string2.match(/(.+?)(?=OR)/g)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```js
var string2 = 'twitter OR facebook AND NOT (hello OR p )',
    result = string2.match(/\w+(?=\s+OR)/g);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

A lazy answer (because the words you need are lowercase) :

```js
var a = "twitter OR facebook AND NOT (hello OR p )";
arr = a.match(/[a-z]{2,20}/g); 
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

One immediate problem is that by using `(.+?)` you're selecting every character that comes before OR. This will include spaces and parenthesis. Essentially everything after the first OR and before the second OR is selected.

You can change that to `\w+?` to select only word characters.

The second problem is that you need to, at the minimum check for spaces before your OR keyword, but can also check for spaces afterwards so that it doesn't match words like `OREGAN` or `BORING`.

```js
var string1 = "twitter OR facebook AND NOT (hello OR p )"
var string2 = "twitter   OR   facebook AND NOT (hello   OR   p )"
var string3 = "twitter OR facebook AND NOT (hello OREGAN p )"

var expr = /(\w+?)(?=\s+OR\s+)/g

var result1 = string1.match(expr)
var result2 = string2.match(expr)
var result3 = string3.match(expr)

console.log(result1, result2, result3)
```